# UNIX - Finding all empty files in source directory & finding files edited X days ago

Tags: unix

The following is from a school assignment.

The question asks

> "What command enables you to find all empty files in your source
>   directory."

My answer; `find -size 0` However, my instructor says that my answer is incorrect. The only hint (Regarding the entirety of the assignment) he gives me is "...minor errors such as missing a file name or outputting too much information" I was thinking, perhaps I should include the source directory within my find command.
I've been trying to figure this out for the past few hours. I've referenced my textbook and according to that I should be correct.
There's some other questions I'm having similar issues with. I've wracked my brain with this for hours. I just don't know. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It's been ages since I've done unix work, but try: `find . -size 0` . Notice the dot (`.`) to tell the command to search in the current folder.

Comment: Thank you, I think that'll answer it!

Comment: You are welcome. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Since your assignment was to *find all empty files in **your source** directory*, the following command will do exactly what you want:

```
find . -size 0
```

Notice the dot (`.`) to tell the command to search in the current folder.

For other folders, you replace the "dot" with the folder you want.